# Clear and Enter Text - Selenium- String is being appended twice- Android and Java

Tags: java, android, selenium

[image]

Attached are the two code snippets I have been using to enter text in EditText fields for android Native app. this method works fine for some while for most of the text boxes the input string is being appended twice. Also the very basic send keys is appending the text twice.

Is there any alternate way to enter text or any way to ask the developers to change the edit text fields implementation??

Comment: Please post the code in thread instead of an image.

Answer (score 0):

If we take a look at the `setText()` method, it's clearly receiving an argument `String textValue`. As per the documentation [**`sendKeys()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#sendKeys-java.lang.CharSequence...-) method accepts **`java.lang.CharSequence`**. So when you are trying to pass that `String` **`textValue`** within `sendKeys()` method, the call to `toString()` looks to me as a overhead.

So ideally you should be removing the call to `toString()` method.

Though I have tested `sendKeys(textValue)` and `sendKeys(textValue.toString())` for the `Google Search` field, it didn't append it twice.

As a wild guess, may be the `String` **`textValue`** is already present in the `HTML DOM` so it never gets cleaned up even on calling `clear()` method. Hence it gets appended.